# Multidimentional Arrays of variable Size without using cells Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array, cells

I need to store multiple measurements which are contained in arrays of variable elements size (their datatype is double ) in an single array so as to use a specific matlab function . The input of this function has to be an array so I can't use the Cell data type and I know that by definition you can't have a different number of elements in different slices of the same dimensions . So my quetion is do you have a suggestion of having an array of arrays of variable size in Matlab without using Cell ?

Thank you .

Comment: Initialise the array according to the largest size and fill the extra indices with zeros/nans or whatever that seems appropriate. Another option is using a struct. But I would go for a cell array, I don't see any reason to avoid its use

Comment: the reason is that the fucntion that i want to use this data for takes as input only a standart array .

Comment: I would fix that function then

Comment: What is that specific function ?

Comment: You can also use `cellfun` to send each cell to the function as an array input

Comment: What function are you calling? How would you call it with a multidimensional array if all of the arrays *were* the same size? Would you pass the multidimensional array all at once, or would you call the function with each individual array in a loop?